# How to switch axes in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I like to switch x axis with y axis after plotting a graph with matplotlib? Any easy way for it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767781/python-matplotlib-way-to-transpose-axes/15859177#15859177 newer duplicate of this post

Comment: Could you please add some more information as to what exactly do you mean by "switch x axis with y axis after plotting a graph"? Do you want to plot the axis transposed? Do you want to store transposed values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python matplotlib: way to transpose axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767781/python-matplotlib-way-to-transpose-axes)

Comment: I'm wondering what the situation is in which you need this, could you explain that?

Answer (score 12):

I guess this would be a way to do it in case you really
want to change data of an existing plot:

execute this code first to get a figure:

```
# generate a simple figure
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8,9])
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])
```

and then use this to switch the data of an existing line

```
# get data from first line of the plot
newx = ax.lines[0].get_ydata()
newy = ax.lines[0].get_xdata()

# set new x- and y- data for the line
ax.lines[0].set_xdata(newx)
ax.lines[0].set_ydata(newy)
```

Comment: What is the first line this solution refers to? Does it mean that if there are >=2 lines, it will fail?

Comment: in case you want to switch multiple lines, simply put it in a loop! (e.g. `for line in ax.lines: ...`

Comment: only work if axis have the same dtype tho!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply switch x and y parameters in the plot function:

```
I[3]: x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 100)

I[4]: y = np.sin(x)

I[5]: plt.plot(x,y)

I[6]: plt.figure(); plt.plot(y,x)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the answer I am seeking. I am asking how to switch x and y axes after I have plotted all data.

Answer (score -1):

Rotate the monitor 90 degrees and look at its mirror image. An O(1) solution.