# Change axis in mapltolib figure

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, axis

Usually matplotlib uses this axis:

```
Y
|
|
|_______X
```

But I need to plot my data using:

```
  _________Y
 |
 |
 |
 X
```

How can I do it? I will prefer not modify my data (i.e. transposing). I need to be able of use the coordinates always and matplotlib changes the axis.

Comment: what kind of plot is it? Certain matplotlib functions have `'orientation'` keyword arguments that may be able to help.

Comment: I am using scatter and PathPatch.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767781/python-matplotlib-way-to-transpose-axes/15859177#15859177

Comment: And if you then need to invert a y-axis, simply call `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the variations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Scatter(x, y):        
    ax.scatter(y, x) 

#Data preparation part:
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  

#Plotting and axis inverting part
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
plt.ylabel('X', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Y', fontsize=15)

ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top') #This send label to top 
plt.gca().invert_yaxis() #This inverts y axis
ax.xaxis.tick_top() #This send xticks to top

#User defined function Scatter
Scatter(x,y)

ax.grid()
ax.axis('scaled') 
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]